# Error Code: 1054. Unkowm column

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, where

Estou querendo consultar um valor a partir de uma conta que fiz no SQL:

`(Valor - (select Visibilidade)) AS Diferenca`

Quando tento fazer a consulta:

`Diferenca <= 500`

Ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown 'Diferenca' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Isso é o que? SqlLite ou mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível utilizar o *alias* na clausula `where`, ao invés disso faça a sua consulta assim:

```
select suasColunas from suaTabela where (Valor - (select Visibilidade)) <= 500
```